# How can I flatten two lists within a list without using data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to form one data.frame from lists within a list

```
L1 <- list(A = c(1, 2, 3), B = c(5, 6, 7))
L2 <- list(A = c(11, 22, 33), B = c(15, 16, 17))
L3 <- list(L1, L2)
L3

library(data.table)
```

According to the 'data.table' manual : "'rbindlist' Same as do.call("rbind",l), but much faster"

I would like to achieve what 'rbindlist' does using R base package

rbindlist does exactly what I need but 'do.call' does not!

```
rbindlist(L3)
```

do.call does not do what I want

```
do.call(rbind, L3)

identical(rbindlist(L3), do.call(rbind, L3))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd think calling `as.data.frame` each time could be costly. How about?

```
as.data.frame(do.call(mapply, c(L3, FUN=c, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)))
```

`mapply` basically takes the first elements of L3 and applies the function `FUN`, then 2nd element and so on... Suppose you'd two lists (`L3[[1]]` and `L3[[2]]`), then you'd do:

```
mapply(FUN=c, L3[[1]], L3[[2]], SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Here `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` makes sure the output is not converted (or simplified) to matrix. Thus it'll be a list. For a general case, we use `do.call` and pass our list with all other arguments for function `mapply`. Hope this helps.

---

Benchmarking on big data:

```
ll <- unlist(replicate(1e3, L3, simplify=FALSE), rec=FALSE)

aa <- function() as.data.frame(do.call(mapply, c(ll, FUN=c, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)))
bb <- function() do.call(rbind, lapply(ll, as.data.frame))

require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(o1 <- aa(), o2 <- bb(), times=10)

Unit: milliseconds
       expr        min         lq     median         uq      max neval
 o1 <- aa()   4.356838   4.931118   5.462995   7.623445  20.5797    10
 o2 <- bb() 673.773795 683.754535 701.557972 710.535860 724.2267    10

identical(o1, o2) # [1] TRUE
```

Comment: +1. Of course, if we are going for speed and the dims of all our list items are the same, and we already know what they are: `A <- unlist(ll, use.names=FALSE); dim(A) <- c(3, 2, 2000); apply(A, 2, I)`. A lot of "if"s though :)

Comment: Thank you Arun, your solution is perfect. However, i don't understand the args = c(applyMeanList, FUN=c, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)) to do.call. can you please provide further explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the sublists in `L3` to `data.frame`s first:

```
> do.call(rbind, lapply(L3, as.data.frame))
   A  B
1  1  5
2  2  6
3  3  7
4 11 15
5 22 16
6 33 17
```